# add a new key value pair to existing key value pair object in python

Tags: python

Python beginner here. I have a dictionary with a key and its value is an object (dict) who also has a key value pair.  I want to add a key value pair to the 'child' object.

given:

```
{"foo" : 
    {"bar" : "bars value"}
}
```

I want to add:

```
{"foo" : 
    {"bar" : "bar value", 
     "baz" : "baz value" 
    }
}
```

This seems incredibly common but I can't seem to find a good way to do it.

Comment: Note: Python objects and dicts are different concepts. Don't use the terms interchangeably.

Comment: Well, a `dict` is an `object`, but not all `object`s are `dict`s.

Comment: The best way to do this often depends on the input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
somedict = {"foo" : 
    {"bar" : "bars value"}
}

somedict['foo']['baz'] = 'baz value'
```

When Python encounters `somedict['foo']['baz']` it first looks-up the value of the bare name `somedict`. It finds it is a `dict`. Then it evaluates `somedict['foo']` and finds it is another dict. Then it assigns to this dict a new key `'baz'` with value `` `baz value' ``.

Answer (score 4):

You can just do

```
mydict["foo"]["baz"] = "baz value"
```

as in

```
>>> mydict = {"foo" : {"bar" : "bars value"}}
>>> mydict["foo"]["baz"] = "baz value"
>>> mydict
{'foo': {'baz': 'baz value', 'bar': 'bars value'}}
```

Comment: a problem is, the appending is happening dynamically so i don't know the k/v of the one i'm appending. is there a way to do this without iterating over the k/v object or object list to be added?

Comment: You'll need to be a bit clearer about what you know when you're writing the code, what you know at runtime, and what you never know at all.

Answer (score 2):

This will work without knowing the key-value pairs inside `dic`:

```
>>> dic = {"foo" : {"bar" : "bars value"}}
...     
>>> pairs = (("baz", "baz value"),)
for k,v in pairs:
    for k1 in dic:
        dic[k1][k]= v
>>> dic
{'foo': {'baz': 'baz value', 'bar': 'bars value'}}
```

Another Example:

```
>>> dic = {"foo" : {"bar" : "bars value"},"bar" : {"bar" : "bars value"} }
>>> pairs = (("baz", "baz value"),)
for k,v in pairs:
    for k1 in dic:
        dic[k1][k]= v
...         
>>> dic
{'foo': {'baz': 'baz value', 'bar': 'bars value'},
 'bar': {'baz': 'baz value', 'bar': 'bars value'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using `update()`:

def updateChild(d, pk, pair):
    d["pk"].update((pair,))

`d` is the whole dictionary, `pk` is the parent key, and `pair` is a tuple of the child key and the update data. This is useful if you have the pair already, as it seems you might in the question title.